# Find the average of a variable compared to fixed variable

Tags: r, average

So I have a short table of demographic data from a survey. Age, income, race, etc.
My HW question is as follows:

I would like you to determine, from your Tulsa data, whether age and income are
significantly related. If so, what is the expected income of a 50-year-old person?

I have the first part, just need to know how to find the mean income of a 50 year old person according to my data.

Comment: This is NOT a HW service. They are not prohibited but just posting naked questions with no code or data will produce various reactions but at the very least will cause annoyance. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Answer (score 0):

step one: measure the correlation, use `cor(x, y)`

step two: use a linear regression (assuming the simpest scenario) with `lm(y ~ x)`.

The result contains intercept and slope to calculate the value of the function, `y = f(x)`, for any values of `x`, like 50 in your question.